# Шифрование и дешифровка текста

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно чтоб программа расшифровывала и зашифровывала текст, но выходит ошибка

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Графическая программа на Python")
root.geometry("700x600")
root["bg"] = 'purple'

pol=Label(root,text='введи слово', font=("Arial Bold", 25),bg="maroon1", fg="thistle1")
pol.grid(column=10, row=0)
ALPHA = Entry(root, width=20)
ALPHA.grid(column=10, row=2) 

def encode(text, step):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans(ALPHA, ALPHA[step:] + ALPHA[:step]))
def decode(text, step):
    return text.translate(str.maketrans(ALPHA[step:] + ALPHA[:step], ALPHA))

btn = Button(root, text="зашифровать",bg="pink", fg="blue",command=decode)
btn.grid(column=5, row=1)
btn2 = Button(root, text="расшифровать",bg="pink", fg="blue",command=encode)
btn2.grid(column=15, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: encode() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'text' and 'step'
```

также я не понимаю куда вообще могу вывести результат

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает из за того, что при нажатии на кнопки btn и btn2 вызываются функции encode и decode, имеющие 2 аргумента, и которым эти аргументы не передаются:

```
btn = Button(root, text="зашифровать",bg="pink", fg="blue",command=decode) #<-- здесь
```

Передать параметры можно либо через lambda функцию, либо через partial (из functools) подробнее [тут](https://www.delftstack.com/ru/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-pass-arguments-to-tkinter-button-command/#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-command-%D0%B2-tkinter-button-%D1%81-partials).

Вывести результат, как по мне, удобнее всего в тот же Entry.
Итого, возможный вариант решения:

```
def encode(text, step):
    res = text #шифруем текст
    ALPHA.delete(0,"end")
    ALPHA.insert(0, res)
def decode(text, step):
    res = text #дешифруем текст
    ALPHA.delete(0,"end")
    ALPHA.insert(0, res)

btn = Button(root, text="зашифровать",bg="pink", fg="blue",command=lambda: encode(ALPHA.get(), 2))
btn.grid(column=5, row=1)
btn2 = Button(root, text="расшифровать",bg="pink", fg="blue",command=lambda: decode(ALPHA.get(), 2))
btn2.grid(column=15, row=1)
```

Но:

- алгоритм "шифрования" не рабочий, его разбирать не стал, оставил передаваемый текст нетронутым: res = text
- не понимаю зачем Вам передавать аргументом step, если он нигде не меняется/задается.

Comment: *алгоритм "шифрования" не рабочий* -наверное, нехорошо, что в ответе будет заведомо неправильный код лежать. Оставьте от функций только pass. Мне кажется, это будет более корректным

Comment: @splash58 внутри функции ещё вывод текста, который нужен ТСу. но подправил